# How do I run MATLAB scripts in parallel (i.e. on multiple cores and without using parfor)?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I am looking for options to run MATLAB scripts I have in parallel without too much hassle.

Is there an example or a simple scenario on how to proceed in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note below MacOSX/Linux are assumed. But `parallel` will work inside envs like `msys` on Windows

This is an example on how to start MATLAB jobs in parallel on your computer (without using `parfor` or the need to rely on Parallel Toolbox license):

```
seq 1 4 | parallel 'matlab -singleCompThread -nojvm -r "myprint({}); exit"'
```

where `myprint.m` is the following MATLAB function (placed in current working directory):

```
cat myprint.m 
function myprint(text)
   disp(text)
end
```

This behaviour can be replicated using Octave: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/

```
seq 1 4 | parallel 'octave --eval "myprint({}); exit"'
```

`parallel` should be installed. More information about the tool can be found at the GNU project homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Some short videos displaying the most common usage are available at: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1. If you prefer a video in Ogg/Theora format: http://tinyogg.com/watch/TORaR/ and http://tinyogg.com/watch/hfxKj/

## Alternative method - compiling the MATLAB code

Another way to avoid relying on the Parallel Toolbox license is to compile to the code as the following

```
mcc -m myprint.m
```

If everything worked fine (i.e. compiled without any errors), you will see a `myprint` executable and a bash script.  To run the script, simply do this in the terminal:

```
run_myprint.sh
```

Find where is your MATLAB installed (either using the `$MATLABROOT` bash variable or `$MCR` [MATLAB runtime folder]).  You can now start your program:

```
./run_myprint.sh /usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b 2
```

You will see

```
------------------------------------------
Setting up environment variables
---
LD_LIBRARY_PATH is .:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/client:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64
2
```

The parallel bash version running the compiled MATLAB code in parallel looks like this:

```
seq 1 4 | parallel './run_myprint.sh /usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b {}'
```

## A word of advice

If your problem and hence your code is embarrassingly parallel, keep it that way.

`parfor` is only truly necessary to uncouple dependencies in your data:

Check here for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel

Comment: I've taken the liberty in reformatting your post.  What you're talking about is good, but it would be better if it was properly formatted and if the grammar was fixed... which is now the case.  Let me know if you agree with the edits.

Comment: Perhaps you could state explicitly what operating system supports these command line arguments.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - Judging from the commands, it's either Mac OS or Linux... but can't say for sure.